# The space-time metric in string theory

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, metric-tensor, compactification, calabi-yau

I always wondered about the metric to be used in string theory. As 10-4  (11-4)  or 26-4 dimensions are supposed to be curled up or being a Calabi-Yau manifold, in this part of the space-time the metric should be non-Minkowski. The consequence would be that one would have to deal with quantum field theory in curved space which is much more complicated  than QFT in a pure Minkowski-metric. I admit, I am not an expert on string theory (so the question might be seem basic for string theory experts)  but I have some knowledge on General relativity, so I am rather curious how this issue is handled.